# Matplotlib Heat-Map Y Axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

Thank you in advance!  (Image provided below)

I am trying to have the Y-Axis of my heatmap reflect the year associated with the data it is pulling. What is happening is that the Y-Axis is merely counting the number of years (0, 1, 2, ....30) when it should be appearing as 1990, 1995, 2000, etc.

**How do I update my code (provided below) so that the Y-Axis shows the actual year instead of the year count?**

```
# links to Minot data if you want to pull from the web
##url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the- 
datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/master/allStationsDailyAirTemp1.csv'
raw_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/the- 
datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/master/allStationsDailyAirTemp1.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df_all_stations = raw_data.copy()

selected_station = 'Minot'

# load the data into a DataFrame, not a Series
# parse the dates, and set them as the index
df1 = df_all_stations[df_all_stations['Station'] == selected_station]



# groupby year and aggregate Temp into a list
dfg1 = df1.groupby(df1.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})

# create a wide format dataframe with all the temp data expanded
df1_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg1.Temp.tolist(), index=dfg1.index)


# adding the data between 1990/01/01 -/04/23 and delete the 29th of Feb
rng = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end='1990-04-23', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(index= rng)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['Temp'] = np.NaN
frames = [df, df1]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result = result[~((result.index.month == 2) & (result.index.day == 29))]

dfg1 = result.groupby(result.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})
df1_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg1['Temp'].tolist(), index=dfg1.index)

# Setting all leftover empty fields to the average of that time in order to fill in the gaps
df1_wide = df1_wide.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)

# ploting the data
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(20, 5))

##ax1.set_title('Average Daily Air Temperature - Minot Station')
ax1.set_xlabel('Day of the year')
ax1.set_ylabel('Years since start of data collection')

# Setting the title so that it changes based off of the selected station
ax1.set_title('Average Air Temp for ' + str(selected_station))

# Creating Colorbar  
cbm = ax1.matshow(df1_wide, interpolation=None, aspect='auto');

# Plotting the colorbar
cb = plt.colorbar(cbm, ax=ax1)
cb.set_label('Temp in Celsius')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line at the end of your code:

```
ax1.set_yticklabels(['']+df1_wide.index.tolist()[::5])
```

[image]

Comment: What you made assumes that all pieces of data begin at 1990.
If you change the station to Bottineau, it begins that graph at 1990 even though it actually began in 1993. 

For example:

Bottineau,1993-01-01,-28.75 - This is the first line of data for the Bottineau station

Comment: How should I change it so that it bases its beginning off of when the selected stations data begins?

Comment: @XavierConzet: It bases on the way you construct `df1_wide`. You hard-coded this line `rng = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end='1990-04-23', freq='D')` for `Minot`. So, if you change station, you need to change it accordingly.

Comment: @XavierConzet: It would require a complete review on the logic to handle stations dynamically. I suggest you should post a new question to get more attention to it.

Comment: Sounds good, I think I will do that. Thank you for all your help.